# Django BooleanField обязательное для заполнения

Tags: django

У меня есть форма в которой есть 4 чекбокса. Первые два чекбокса относятся к выбору доставки - либо самовывоз, либо курьер. Вторые два чекбокса относятся к способу оплаты - либо оплата картой, либо в руки курьеру. Нужно сделать так чтобы из каждой пары было выбрано по 1 обязательно. В противном случае валидация не будет пройдена, `views` уже написан. Просто нужно реализовать обязательное поле в `BooleanField`. Например `text = models.TextField(blank=True)` не дает отправить пустой текст. Нужно что-то подобное и для `Boolean`

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    samovyvoz = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    courier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    online_pay = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hand_pay = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
from orders.models import Order
from django import forms

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['samovyvoz', 'courier', 'online_pay', 'hand_pay']
```

**order_create.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Выбор доставки - город Москва <span class="label_red">*</span></h1>
    <p>
        <input class="first_grp_check" type="checkbox" name="samovyvoz" value="samovyvoz">
        <label for="samovyvoz">Самовывоз</label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input class="first_grp_check" type="checkbox" name="courier" value="courier">
        <label for="courier">Курьер - 300 рублей</label>
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>Способ оплаты <span class="label_red">*</span></h1>
    <p>
        <input class="second_grp_check" type="checkbox" name="online_pay" value="online_pay">
        <label for="online_pay">Онлайн оплата картой</label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input class="second_grp_check" type="checkbox" name="hand_pay" value="hand_pay">
        <label for="hand_pay">Оплата при получении</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, Вам подойдёт поле с выбором?

Пример:

```py
DELIVERY_CHOICES = [
    ('К', 'Курьер'),
    ('С', 'Самовывоз')
]

delivery = models.CharField(choices=DELIVERY_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Кстати, так намного проще. И незаполненным не отправляется. Спасибо!